# Is there any counterexample of integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

When $G(x)$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$ and $G'(x)$ is Riemann-integrable in this interval, and $f(x)$ is integrable in $G([a,b])$, is there any example that makes $$\int_a^bf(G(x))G'(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ non-integrable or
$$\int_{G(a)}^{G(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\neq\int_a^bf(G(x))G'(x)\,\mathrm dx\text{ ?} $$

Comment: @Simon The OP has weakened the hypotheses of the standard theorem on change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Bagby[$1$] has proven a stronger result, namely that if $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, $G(x) - G(a) = \int_a^x g(t) \ dt$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $f$ is Riemann integrable on $G[a,b]$ then

$$\int_{G(a)}^{G(b)} f(u) \ du = \int_a^b g(t) \cdot  \left(f\circ G\right)(t) \ dt$$

[$1$] R. J. Bagby, *The substitution theorem for Riemann integrals*, Real Anal.
Exchange $27$
($2001/02$), $309–314$.